# How to pass numeric value into find() element in ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django-templates

I am trying to add upvote/downvote option in comments in my django blog.I used ajax to achieve this functionality.Finally I want to pass the value to update upvote_count for comment in **comments thread**.

First problem I am facing here that I am not able to select the id of the element where I want to update the upvote_count.I tried `$(this).find('span')` to select the element.But later I am unable to pass the value to that element.Here is my code:

```
<button class="btn btn-link text-dark p-0 border-0 btn-outline-light" id="upvote-button" 
               data-upvoteid = "{{comment.id}}"
               value="{{ comment.id }}">
        <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
        <span class="" id="upvote_count" data-upvotecount = "{{comment.id}}">
         {{comment.upvote_count}}</span>
</button>




<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#upvote-button', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{% url "upvote" %}',
        data: {
          commentid: $(this).attr("data-upvoteid"),
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
          action: 'post'
        },
        success: function (json) {  
       
         // This line is not working.
         $(this).find('span').get().innerHTML = json['result'];
       
        },
        error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
    
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Now,
**How can I pass the value to that element?** or
**Is there any better way to identify the element instead of using find()?**

Comment: what if you just `$(this).find('span').text(json['result']);`

Comment: Thanks for comment but it is not working.

Comment: are yiou sure, that json['result'] returns anything then? are you getting any console errors? What do you get from console.log(json)?'

Comment: @Stender      It is showing {result: 1}  or {result: 0} as I want to increment upvote_count to 1 if someone clicked upvoted once or decrement if anyone clicked twice.

Comment: Your ajax don't know what is `$(this)` so you can add this line `var selector = $(this)` before your ajax call and then do like `selector.find('span').text(json['result']);`

Comment: @Swati         Yes, It worked :) Thanks.